# CASE statement - Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, case

I need to convert date to string in a case statement as following, but I get an error

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

```
CASE
  WHEN Code='X' and Category=1 THEN X_Col
  WHEN Code='Y' THEN Y_Col
  WHEN Code='Z' THEN CAST(Z_Col AS nvarchar(20))
END AS Res
```

I know that if it was like the following would be ok but I need to check two columns in some cases

```
CASE Code
 WHEN 'X' THEN X_Col
 WHEN 'Y' THEN Y_Col
 WHEN 'Z' THEN CAST(Z_Col AS nvarchar(20))
END AS Res
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not because of using 2 conditions in a case, but because of datatypes of 3 cases might fall different.

In the end case condition will produce 1 column. So the `then` statement should have only 1 datatype.

Change your case as

```
CASE
  WHEN Code='X' and Category=1 THEN CAST(X_Col AS nvarchar(20))
  WHEN Code='Y' THEN CAST(Y_Col AS nvarchar(20))
  WHEN Code='Z' THEN CAST(Z_Col AS nvarchar(20))
END AS Res
```

Comment: Actually that's not exactly right. If the implicit covert works you can return difference types and the engine will handle this.

Comment: Yes, suggesting best practice is not a bad idea. However sometimes implicite conversion of sql server also bottle neck for perfomance issues. @gotqn

Comment: Yes I agree for sure this is a good practice, but it is not a must as and the official documentation says.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
CASE
  WHEN Code='X' and Category=1 THEN CAST(X_Col nvarchar(20))
  WHEN Code='Y' THEN CAST(Y_Col nvarchar(20))
  WHEN Code='Z' THEN CAST(Z_Col AS nvarchar(20))
END AS Res
```

The return type of the expression is the highest precedence type from the set of types in result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) you can see the data type precedence. So, I guess one of your values is numeric/int and the conversion fails.